# Merging second column values for unique first column values

Tags: sql-server

Below is my table records.

```
  Folder1    File1

  Folder1    File2

  Folder2    File3

  Folder2    File4
```

But i need the result set like this as shown below.

```
  Folder1   File1,File2

  Folder2   File3,File4
```

Could you please provide me the sql query to achieve this?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35746138/ms-sql-group-by-concat-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Simple stuff**

```
Select X.Folder,
stuff((Select ','+ Z.File from Table Z Where X.Folder =Z.Folder For XML Path('')),1,1,'')
from Table X
Group by X.Folder
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - mohan